# How to convert string date : "Mon Nov 12 08:00:00 ICT 2012" to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

This is my way to convert but it's not work:

```
 string date = "Mon Nov 12 08:00:00 ICT 2012";
 DateTime dateConvert = 
          DateTime.ParseExact(date, 
                              "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 Console.WriteLine(dateConvert);
```

so, how to convert it? Thankyou!

Comment: What is your error code or unexptected output ?

Answer (score 2):

Your format string for the DateTime.ParseExact should be `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'ICT' yyyy`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx on the details on DateTime format strings.

Answer (score 0):

PARSE EXACT means you're telling it to expect:

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

But your input string is not in that format!!!

You need something like:

```
 ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \I\C\T yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got wrong is that the format you provide to DateTime.ParseExact is supposed to be the format of the date string coming in, not what you want coming out.

Try something like:

```
string date = "Mon Nov 12 08:00:00 ICT 2012";
DateTime dateConvert = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'ICT' yyyy", null);
Console.WriteLine(dateConvert.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: DateTime.Parse will most probably not recognize the format of the given date.

Comment: This does not work. "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "Mon Nov 12 08:00:00 ICT 2012";

DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss ICT yyyy", null);

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: thanks so much. But if you replace "null" = "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" its true!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all care! This is my solution and it's work cool!

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Nov 12 08:00:00 ICT 2012", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss ICT yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```